# sshfs LocalForward without config file

Tags: port-forwarding, sshfs

I'm trying to add portforwarding to my sshfs-mount-scripts:

```
sshfs tim@devserver1:/ /home/tim/mnt/devserver1/ 
-o SSHOPT=LocalForward 127.0.0.5:3306 127.0.0.1:3306
```

So far I've failed using the correct syntax. Using brackets or commas instead of spaces did not work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, that is not possible with `-o`. The list of `ssh` options supported by `sshfs` can be found [in the source code](http://sourceforge.net/p/fuse/sshfs/ci/sshfs_2_5/tree/sshfs.c#l271):

```
static const char *ssh_opts[] = {
        "AddressFamily",
        "BatchMode",
        "BindAddress",
        "ChallengeResponseAuthentication",
        "CheckHostIP",
        "Cipher",
        "Ciphers",
        "Compression",
        "CompressionLevel",
        "ConnectionAttempts",
        "ConnectTimeout",
        "ControlMaster",
        "ControlPath",
        "GlobalKnownHostsFile",
        "GSSAPIAuthentication",
        "GSSAPIDelegateCredentials",
        "HostbasedAuthentication",
        "HostKeyAlgorithms",
        "HostKeyAlias",
        "HostName",
        "IdentitiesOnly",
        "IdentityFile",
        "KbdInteractiveAuthentication",
        "KbdInteractiveDevices",
        "LocalCommand",
        "LogLevel",
        "MACs",
        "NoHostAuthenticationForLocalhost",
        "NumberOfPasswordPrompts",
        "PasswordAuthentication",
        "Port",
        "PreferredAuthentications",
        "ProxyCommand",
        "PubkeyAuthentication",
        "RekeyLimit",
        "RhostsRSAAuthentication",
        "RSAAuthentication",
        "ServerAliveCountMax",
        "ServerAliveInterval",
        "SmartcardDevice",
        "StrictHostKeyChecking",
        "TCPKeepAlive",
        "UsePrivilegedPort",
        "UserKnownHostsFile",
        "VerifyHostKeyDNS",
        NULL,
};
```

If it were supported, the syntax would be `sshfs -o 'LocalForward=....'`

In addition, `sshfs` [passes the `-oClearAllForwardings=yes` option](http://sourceforge.net/p/fuse/sshfs/ci/sshfs_2_5/tree/sshfs.c#l3835), so even the forwarding defined in `~/.ssh/config` are not honoured.

Since `sshfs` supports passing a `ssh_command`, and allows additional arguments there, what you can do instead is:

```
CODE='
  for i do
    [ "$i" = -oClearAllForwardings=yes ] &&
      i="-oLocalForward=127.0.0.5:3306 127.0.0.1:3306"
    set -- "$@" "$i"
    shift
  done
  exec ssh "$@"
' sshfs -o ssh_command='/bin/sh -c eval\\ "$CODE" sh' user@host:/path mnt
```

Answer (score 1):

just building on [@Stéphane Chazelas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/109606/149714) answer sshfs passes the `-oClearAllForwardings=yes` option so any forwarding that is defined will not be honoured

so this behavior can be overwritten by passing `-oClearAllForwarding=no` instead, this can be done as follows

```
sshfs -o 'ssh_command=ssh -oClearAllForwardings=no' user@host:/path/to/remote/directory /path/to/local/directory
```

you can additionally pass the LocalForwarding option as follows:

```
sshfs -o 'ssh_command=ssh -oClearAllForwarding=no -L 3309:127.0.0.1:3309' user@host:/path/to/remote/directory /path/to/local/directory
```

shameless plug: I've written a script to simplify mounting with sshfs called [sshmount](https://github.com/fuseteam/sshmount) it sets a few sane default options such as `reconnect`, `ServerAliveInterval=15`, `sshfs_sync` and `sync_readdir` based on my own experience with sshfs and a few tips i recently received and
as of today it will also have an option `-F` to not clear all forwardings and an option -S to specify ssh options xD